# display:none vs jQuery remove()

Tags: jquery, css

Is it ok to think that using

`(.class).remove()`

is better for the website's loading time rather than using
`.class {display:none}`

Comment: `.remove()` will change the node list of the parents because it involves removing a DOM node. `display: none` does not involve DOM node removal. Although in most cases, both will result in a repaint anyway. Remember that `display: none` does not remove the element from the DOM, too.

Comment: If you want to play around with elements later in document then use display:none else .remove() is best.

Answer (score 3):

> The display property is the most important CSS property for
>   controlling layout.

```
display:none;
```

Is a value for the display property which simply hides the HTML element from the user view.
If used the user won't see the selected element but if you open the page HTML source you will be able to see the element.
And [there are many different ways to hide an HTML element](http://techblog.treenodes.com/index.php/2016/09/05/different-ways-to-hide-an-html-element/) from the user view.

[jQuery Remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

> Description: Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

It is a jQuery JavaScript function which edit the HTML and remove the selected element completely from the page, so if you opened the HTML source you won't find the element there.

Which is faster?  there are 2 different things so I am not sure how to compare, but lets say you need to just hide an element on page load, for sure CSS will be faster than calling a JavaScript library method whatever it is, so I would prefer using CSS over JavaScript when possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are wanting to compare $('.class').hide() and .class{display:none} .

$('.class').remove() deletes the entire element from the page, it just doesn't hide it. At the end of day CSS will be faster. JQuery always has that extra step of being parsed into javascript, then that javascript being parsed to select all the DOM elements and loop through them applying the CSS.

So at the end of the day you will still be applying CSS to the elements but with about 2-3 extra steps. You can skip all those steps by just instantaneously applying the CSS yourself with .class {display:none;}.

At the end of the day, that is sort of trivial to worry about though, the performance difference will be less than a fraction of a second, unless you are working with 1000s and 1000s of elements.

If you are really wanting to compare $('.class').remove() the same concept still applies.

Comment: Thank you guys, very helpful.